# React ввод и вывод номера карты

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input

Мне нужно на ReactJS при помощи `input` сделать что бы при вводе, и последующем выводе на экран по нужному паттерну.

То есть, при вводе нужно чтобы после каждого 4го символа ставился пробел:

`1234 5678 9012 3456`

и при выводе одновременно с вводом выводилось этот же номер с таким же паттерном, то есть с пробелами.

```
const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState("0000 0000 0000 0000");

<input 
    type="number"
    className="card-number-input"
    onChange={(e) => setCardNum(e.target.value.toString().replace(/\d{4}(?=.)/g, '$& '))}
    maxLength={16} 
/>

<p>{cardNumber}</p>
```

В `onChange` решается вопрос вывода, однако ввод по паттерну не проводится

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427046/how-to-add-space-between-every-4-characters-in-javascript

Comment: @soledar10 работает от части, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

на javascript когда то делал
вот такие маски

1. [для денег](http://edms.1gb.ru/K.html)
2. [для карты](http://edms.1gb.ru/c.html)

   let input = document.getElementsByClassName("numberCart");

console.log(input.length);

```
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    
        input[i].addEventListener("keyup", (e) => { formatCart(e.target); });
        input[i].addEventListener("keypress", (e) => { formatCart(e.target); });
        
    }
    function formatCart(input) {
        var input_val = input.value;
        if (input_val === "") { return; }
        var original_len = input_val.length;
        var caret_pos = input.selectionStart;
        input_val = input_val.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
        input.value = input_val;
        var updated_len = input_val.length;
        caret_pos = updated_len - original_len + caret_pos;
        input.setSelectionRange(caret_pos, caret_pos);
    }
```

возможно взять за основу
при вводе пробел устанавливался автоматически